# Why do I see installable triggers in my source google apps script that is published as a Sheets add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need help with understanding installable triggers.
I developed a ***Sheets add-on*** and I need to add some function to run when user renames a tab (sheet). As I understand it is possible only when using the **onChange** installable triggers (there is no such simple trigger).

My add-on has a menu to open a sidebar. When clicking that menu, my function first checks and creates a trigger if it does not exist:

```
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t=>t.getHandlerFunction() == 'gsOnChange').length==0){
    console.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),'Added trigger: gsOnChange()')
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('gsOnChange').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onChange().create()
  }
```

The add-on will be used by thousands of users in thousands of spreadsheets. I expect that trigger to be created for the current spreadsheet.

1. So why do I see multiple triggers in ***my source script project***? I would expect that trigger to be bound to the spreadsheet it was created for.
2. Is there any better approach to handle "on sheet rename" events in Sheets add-ons?

Many thanks in advance!!!

[image]

Comment: From a logic perspective it would kinda make sense that you are receiving the results from the trigger executions on your code as the trigger is calling the function from your script and installable triggers run based on the user that installed them, however, are those other users some test accounts that you have tried testing your add on with?

Comment: Thanks @GabrielCarballo, yes, I used 2 different accounts and installed my add-on from the marketplace. Now I can see 2 additional triggers created in my script. Since the add-on will be used by many users, meaning it will create thousands of triggers under my script. I'm just wondering if this is ok and if there is any limitation it may hit or if there is any better approach to implement such simple onSheetRename functionality?

Answer (score 1):

The situation with the `Triggers` being installed in your add-on script is expected as the triggers are bound to the `script` and not to the Google sheet. Pretty much your code is currently creating a `Trigger` based on the active user making changes on the active Spreadsheet. Now, as these triggers are pretty much created by other users you will notice that they can't be deleted as you can only make changes to `Triggers` that are created by your account. Now, related to Trigger creation there is a limit of 20 per user per script that you can verify in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

Now, if your add-on is meant to modify or check the specific change for spreadsheet of the users you need to consider that the quotas that I posted above, however if it's only one trigger that it is required per user this shouldn't reach the limit of trigger creation as it's based on user created trigger meaning that a user can only create up to 20 triggers on the same script, in your scenario it seems that the trigger will be created based on the user running the function.

Related to the approach on how to handle "on sheet rename" events, it would be better to create a separated question.

Comment: Many thanks @GabrielCarballo, it is making it much more clear.
The doc link does not mention any trigger number limit per script, so I assume it is ok to have triggers created by many users as long as each user has <=20 triggers

Also as I understand, ScriptApp.newTrigger().forSpreadsheet()

Comment: But what if somebody is using my add-on in  >20 documents? As I understand they need to create a separate trigger for each Spreadsheet, right?`ScriptApp.newTrigger().forSpreadsheet()`
In that case it is very easy to go over that limit

Comment: Due to the issue with the onChange events trigger I recommend that you open a different question with more information about what the function really does and see if it can be tackled from a different perspective.